# Issues with Sabre SOAP API EPS_EXT_ProfileReadRQ in .Net

Tags: .net, sabre

I built a simple project to test EPS_EXT_ProfileReadRQ soap api from sabre which I'm able to consume just fine using soapUI tool.  Very simple and basic scenario to retrieve a Profile via the API.  Used the "Add Service Reference" on VS2013 to build my proxy class then create a simple interface to implement the call.  My interface looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using getSabreProfile.EPS_ProfileReadService;

namespace getSabreProfile.Service
{
    public interface IGetProfileService
    {
        Sabre_OTA_ProfileReadRS getProfile(string Token, string Domain, string ProfileId);
    }

    public class GetProfileService : IGetProfileService
    {
        private EPS_ProfileReadPortTypeClient service = new EPS_ProfileReadPortTypeClient();

        public GetProfileService()
        {

        }

        public Sabre_OTA_ProfileReadRS getProfile(string Token, string Domain, string ProfileId)
        {
            var _security = new Security
            {
                BinarySecurityToken = Token
            };

            var _messageHeader = new MessageHeader
            {
                From = new From
                {
                    PartyId = new PartyId[1] { new PartyId { Value ="Client" } }
                },
                To = new To
                {
                    PartyId = new PartyId[1] { new PartyId { Value = "Sabre" } }
                },
                CPAId = "CL41",
                ConversationId = "Profiles",
                Action = "EPS_EXT_ProfileReadRQ",
                MessageData = new MessageData
                {
                    RefToMessageId = "Profiles Get Profile",
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                }
            };

            var _sabre_OTA_ProfileReadRQ = new Sabre_OTA_ProfileReadRQ
            {
                Version = "6.19",
                Item = new ProfileType
                {
                    TPA_Identity = new ProfileTypeTPA_Identity
                    {
                        UniqueID = ProfileId,
                        DomainID = Domain,
                        ClientCode = "TN",
                        ProfileTypeCode = ProfileTypeInfo.TVL,
                        ClientContextCode = "MYS"
                    }
                }
            };

            var response = service.EPS_ProfileReadRQ(ref _messageHeader, ref _security, _sabre_OTA_ProfileReadRQ);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just instantiate the interface from my program:

```
private void btnGetProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetProfileService _getProfile = new GetProfileService();

    var res = _getProfile.getProfile(tbToken.Text, tbDomain.Text, tbProfileId.Text);
}
```

The app compiles with no errors but at run-time I get an error:

```
There was an error in serializing one of the headers in message EPS_ProfileReadRQRequest: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).

error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'getSabreProfile.EPS_ProfileReadService.IgnoreReadSubjectAreasType' to 'getSabreProfile.EPS_ProfileReadService.PartialReadSubjectAreasType'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'getSabreProfile.EPS_ProfileReadService.PartialReadSubjectAreasType' to 'getSabreProfile.EPS_ProfileReadService.IgnoreReadSubjectAreasType'
```

It seems to me like VS2013 is not correctly generating the proxy class for the web service and mapping of types is not correctly parsed but I'm stuck on finding a solution.  I'm willing to manually tuning the proxy class code but have no idea where to change and what lol!.. I hope someone can help here.

Thanks!

Comment: wsdl.exe http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/ServicesPlatform/EnhancedAirBook3.3.0RQ.wsdl /o:SabreEnhancedAirBook3.3.0RQ.vb /l:vb    i generate proxy calss manually like this.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work :-(.. are you able to consume the specific web service EPS_EXT_ProfileReadRQ? I have many other SOAP messages implemented, only this one I'm having issues with... VS2013 already using wsdl.exe when you add as a service reference,

Comment: @Carlos - Just curious if you made any progress.  I've had success in the past in VS2012 with the older profile methods, but these newer Sabre Profiles methods are giving me some trouble.  However, I am now using VS2017 and running wsdl.exe outside of VS to generate the proxy classes.  There is a tweak to the proxy class that I had to do, but it is not related to your error.  Thx.